# Emulating removable storage in KitKat

Tags: android, emulation, android-4.4-kitkat, genymotion, removable-storage

I am currently developing an app that will enable the user to choose where to save files it downloads (external and removable storage). As this app will also support KitKat, I am trying to find a way through the "external storage jungle".

As far as I've already found out, an app has writable dirs on the internal, external and removable storage that are all returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()`.

I am now trying to test this, but as I don't have a physical device running KitKat, I am hoping to emulate a device running KitKat that has removable storage (SD Card) connected, so that `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()` returns more than one folder.

Does anyone know how to achieve that in Genymotion or the default emulator, or maybe know any other emulator or remote testing lab?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just for clarification, internal storage means that it is the data that can be accessed by the app only. Dont confuse internal/external with removeable/fixed storage

Comment: @harvey_slash all folders returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` are private to my app.

Comment: No. That is incorrect. All external folders are not private. They can all be read by all other apps.

Comment: @greenapps Hm, at least the one on removable storage, which I am concentrating on, is only writable by my app (On KitKat I mean). You are right about the others though, sorry.

Comment: How do you know that only your app can write if you don't have a device or a suitable emulator?

Comment: @greenapps To be honest, it's rather an assumption I made while trying to see some sense behind the new removable storage policy ;)

Comment: Ok. Further your idea to use getExternalFilesDirs() and let the user choose from those dirs is ok in my opinion. That would be enough for kitkat as your app can never write anywhere else. For earlier versions it is too limited as users want to be able to place files/directories on micro sd card where they want. If you make this a settings/menu option you could make it flexible by allowing the user to type in the path. Or add a simple directory chooser to your app.

Comment: @greenapps In order to let the user choose, I need to distinguish the `File`s I get from `getExternalFilesDirs()`. In order to test that, I need a suitable Emulator. I do have plans for settings, backwards-compatibility and all, but that's not the point of the question. (No offense, just want to get this back to topic)

Comment: FYI: On my kitkat 4.4.2 device with a micro SD card installed getExternalFilesDirs() only returns one item. That is of external memory. The removable path is not mentioned. That is while on this device the whole removable memory is write protected. So there are no app specific directories where this is allowed according to google. The manufacturer of the tablet can be blamed having done this. So be prepared for all.

Comment: Hm, thank you very much for testing that! I am somewhat at the mercy of the official docs, and they are more than shallow on the topic. So any app can only read from the removable storage on your device?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately. The manufacturer went further that google.

Comment: @greenapps Argh! Who is the manufacturer of your device?

Comment: It is a Medion Lifetab S7852 made in China by Lenovo.

Comment: @greenapps I just googled Medion and found this in the official wikipedia: `Medion AG is an _awful_ German consumer electronics company.` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medion That brings it to the point!

Comment: No it is a very good company. I have many devices (laptops/radios) from them and they are all ok. This tablet is also very fine. It is such a nice tablet that i did not return it, when i found out about the write protection, although i could.